# Restoring NuGet fails with Rider-EAP on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, nuget, rider

I created a project on Windows in VS. After I cloned it on Mac OS X and opened it with JetBrains Rider-EAP, I can't restore Nuget packages.

I can't install or upgrade any packages. Rider throws the following error for each package:

```
ReSharperHostException
     A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. One or more errors occurred. Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3' already exists in project 'MovieLensMongo'
     --- EXCEPTION #1/5 [PackageAlreadyInstalledException]
     Message = “Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3' already exists in project 'MovieLensMongo'”
     ExceptionPath.1 = Root.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException
     ExceptionPath.2 = Root.InnerException.InnerExceptions.#0.InnerException.InnerException
     ExceptionPath.3 = Root.InnerException.InnerException.InnerExceptions.#0.InnerException
     ExceptionPath.4 = Root.InnerException.InnerExceptions.#0.InnerExceptions.#0.InnerException
     ClassName = NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageAlreadyInstalledException
     HResult = COR_E_EXCEPTION=80131500
     --- Outer ---
```

When I create a new project, I don't get any of these errors. I can install or upgrade new packages without any problems.

Does anybody have a similar issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Rider version RS-144.5342 (Windows) there is now a "Restore" button on the "Options" tab of the NuGet window.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem.

Currently Rider does not support restoring NuGet packages (https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/documentation/rider_survival_guide.html#using-nuget):

*Rider does not yet support package restore before build — use nuget.exe restore from the command line for now. This functionality will be added as the EAP progresses.*